# Recording function calls to a library

Tags: linux, logging, wrapper

I am trying to find a tool which will generate wrappers around a library and record all the function calls. The project I am working on is quite large and the 3rd party refuses to dive into such a large codebase to debug their problem. Any suggestions?

PS: I am working on linux.

Comment: The library is written in c. My codebase in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ltrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ltrace) might do just that.

If that's now powerful enough, you can clobber something together thus: assuming you have a debug build with the symbols available, you could extract those symbols and write a script which inserts breakpoints into gdb based on that, runs it, and iteratively extract the location and continue.

Or you could go raw and use [ptrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace).

Comment: `ltrace` should be the best solution.

You can use `-l` to trace only a particular set of libraries.